# Prevent element transition with jQuery sider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a main element that contains the contents of my page and a right side menu bar(I used [jquery sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/)). when I click on the "right menu" link, the menu opens, but pushes the main div to the left side.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <div id="main_div style="position:absolute; z-index:20;"> 
        <a id="right-menu" href="#right-menu">Right Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div id="sidr" style="position:fixed">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#right-menu').sidr({
      name: 'sidr',
      side: 'right'
    });
});
</script>
```

The `z-index` of the sidr element is 10 and it's less than the z-index of main element. I would like to open the sidr on the main element without pushing aside the main element to left side. How can I do this? Thanks...

Comment: Likely, when the menu opens, it triggers a transition on your `main` element; we would need to see more code for this - do you happen to have a live website where this behavior is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the sidr documentation page it says you have the option to turn off the displacement of the body content:

`jQuery(selector).sidr( [options] )`

> displace (Boolean) Default: true [ Version 1.2.0 an above ]
>
> Displace the body content or not.